# Why can't I see ajax slide show images when I run?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, slideshow

I'd like to have an ajax slideshow on my web site. I get image urls from a database.

I think the code is right,but when I debug it my database photos are not shown.

I'm sure that my photos load completely.

```
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div align="center">
    <asp:Image ID="imgslides" runat="server" Height="400px" 
    ImageUrl="Gallery images/72007_205.jpg" BorderColor="Black" 
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5 px" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="Prev" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnPlay" runat="server" Text="Play"  />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next"  />
    <ajax:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" 
    runat="server" AutoPlay="true" Loop="true"    
    NextButtonID="btnNext" 
    PreviousButtonID="btnPrevious" 
    PlayButtonID="btnPlay" 
    PlayButtonText="Play" 
    StopButtonText="Stop"
    TargetControlID="imgslides" 
    SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" 
    SlideShowServicePath = "Slideshow.asmx">
    </ajax:SlideShowExtender>
```

and this is my web service code Slideshow.asmx

```
     public AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection();
        myconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PARISA-PC;Initial Catalog=Images;Integrated Security=True";
        myconn.Open();
        string selectCmd = "select * from images";
        string countCmd = "select count(*) from images";
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(selectCmd,myconn);
        SqlCommand myCmd2 = new SqlCommand(countCmd,myconn);
        int i = 0;
        SqlDataReader dr = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ar.Add(dr.GetString(2));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        myconn.Close();
        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] Photos = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[ar.Count];
           for(i=0 ; i< ar.Count ; i++){
           Photos[i] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide(ar[i].ToString(),"image"+i.ToString(),"Booth's images");

       } 
        return Photos;


    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMw4S.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use http handler or an aspx page (which showing images from database). Then you can send the Query String to that handler or aspx for a particular image from ajax slide web service. You can get enough examples in google about it.